# D Lang: std.bitmanip read data into struct

Tags: d

I found this function: https://dlang.org/phobos/std_bitmanip.html#.read

```
T read(T, Endian endianness = Endian.bigEndian, R)(ref R range)
    if (canSwapEndianness!T && isInputRange!R && is(ElementType!R : const(ubyte)));
```

But I can't understand how to make reading from data into structure.

Is it possible to use something like this?

```
struct MyType {
    uint value;        

    this(ubyte act) { // wtf.peek!ubyte();
        switch (act) {
            case 0:
                value = wtf.read!uint();
                break;
            case 1:
                wtf.read!ubyte(); // seek
                value = wtf.read!uint() | 0x7;
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
}
...
buffer.read!MyType();
```

Comment: it is not really clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I just want to read from ubyte[] into my structure. Structure MyType is a realization for packed uint. For example, it reads 4 bytes when the first byte equals 0, or seeks one byte and reads 4 bytes when the first byte equals 1. It has a dynamic size. It also can return the first byte and do nothing yet. And I want to use something like `auto packed_uint = buffer.read!MyType();`. I can write some wrapper, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the structure of your code - where does `wtf` come from?

It seems to me you've misunderstood what to pass to `MyType`'s constructor - you probably should pass it the range, and read off of that with `std.bitmanip.read`. I might have misunderstood your code, though:

```
import std.range;
import std.bitmanip;

struct MyType {
    uint value;
    this(R)(auto ref R rng) if (isInputRange!R && is(ElementType!R : const(ubyte)))
    {
        auto act = rng.peek!ubyte;
        switch (act) {
            case 0:
                value = rng.read!uint;
                break;
            case 1:
                rng.read!ubyte;
                value = rng.read!uint;
                break;
            // ...
            default: assert(0);
        }
    }
}

unittest {
    ubyte[] buffer = [0x01,0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78];
    auto a = MyType(buffer);
    assert(buffer.length == 0);
    assert(a.value == 0x12345678);
}
```

As you can see, I simply call `MyType`'s constructor with the array as parameter, but you could also wrap it in a `read` function if you really want to:

```
alias read = std.bitmanip.read;
T read(T : MyType, R)(auto ref R range)
if (isInputRange!R && is(ElementType!R : const(ubyte)))
{
    return MyType(range);
}
unittest {
    ubyte[] buffer = [0x01,0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78];
    auto a = buffer.read!MyType;
    assert(buffer.length == 0);
    assert(a.value == 0x12345678);
}
```

Comment: Amazing! That's what I need. Thank you so much for the code.